# Do I need to use SteamWorks in my game to have it on steam?

Tags: steam

Do I need to use SteamWorks in my game to have it on steam? The website talks about it however it does not state it is necessary so I am asking if it is.

I am not asking *how* to do it I'm asking *if* I need to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to implement Steamworks functionality in a Java game? How?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72540/is-it-possible-to-implement-steamworks-functionality-in-a-java-game-how)

Comment: It's not necessary

Comment: Although I am not the OP, I have to say @SethBattin I don't see how this question can be a duplicate of the one you link. The other is asking whether SteamWorks can be implemented in a Java game, while this one asks whether SteamWorks is even necessary for a game to be on Steam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you do not. Everything Steam provides is optional to use by the developer.

If I remember correctly The Binding of Isaac, the original one, was written in Flash and had no chance of ever integrating the C++ Steam SDK. As a result there was no Steamworks support or Steamworks DRM on the game.